# Google Hangouts is still goes into phone storage

Tags: google-play-store, 4.4-kitkat, insufficient-memory, google-hangouts

Recently I have changed my android device default app storage location as SD card by changing adb shell. My android version is 4.42 Kitkat. After doing this, it's working well with most apps that correctly going into External storage. But Google hangouts is still going to phone storage. Why Hangouts go to phone storage. Can i solve that?

Comment: Might be due to how Hangouts works.

Answer (score 0):

Google does not support the Moving of Hangouts to SD. you can, of course, [root](/questions/tagged/root) your device, and use [Link2SD](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://play.google.com/store/apps/details%3Fid%3Dcom.buak.Link2SD%26hl%3Den_GB%26referrer%3Dutm_source%253Dgoogle%2526utm_medium%253Dorganic%2526utm_term%253Dlink2sd%26pcampaignid%3DAPPU_1_mzQPWPjqHIjTgAa2kp64Cw&ved=0ahUKEwi4pOWj4PXPAhWIKcAKHTaJB7cQ8oQBCBwwAA&usg=AFQjCNF_fx4Q42Zqe_r6vJTw20WUtZ3_QA&sig2=qvAqoKFzQ0kCgS2UX0XvIQ) To force the app over